# How do I programmatically determine operating system in Java?

Tags: java, operating-system

I would like to determine the operating system of the host that my Java program is running programmatically (for example: I would like to be able to load different properties based on whether I am on a Windows or Unix platform). What is the safest way to do this with 100% reliability?

Answer (score 730, accepted):

You can use:

```
System.getProperty("os.name")
```

P.S. You may find this code useful:

```
class ShowProperties {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.getProperties().list(System.out);
    }
}
```

All it does is print out all the properties provided by your Java implementations. It'll give you an idea of what you can find out about your Java environment via properties. :-)

Comment: I'm using `Windows 10` and yet `os.name` gives me `Windows 8.1`. Why is that? Where is this coming from?

Comment: nvm found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909107/javas-os-name-for-windows-10

Answer (score 197):

As indicated in other answers, System.getProperty provides the raw data.  However, the [Apache Commons Lang component](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) provides a [wrapper for java.lang.System](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/SystemUtils.html) with handy properties like [`SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/SystemUtils.html#IS_OS_WINDOWS), much like the aforementioned Swingx OS util.

Answer (score 104):

Oct. 2008:

I would recommend to cache it in a static variable:

```
public static final class OsUtils
{
   private static String OS = null;
   public static String getOsName()
   {
      if(OS == null) { OS = System.getProperty("os.name"); }
      return OS;
   }
   public static boolean isWindows()
   {
      return getOsName().startsWith("Windows");
   }

   public static boolean isUnix() // and so on
}
```

That way, every time you ask for the Os, you do not fetch the property more than once in the lifetime of your application.

---

February 2016: 7+ years later:

There is a bug with Windows 10 (which did not exist at the time of the original answer).
See "[Java's “os.name” for Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31909887/6309)"

Comment: I agree with the getOSName function, on the basis of OAOO (once and only once); however, the caching is totally redundant given the speed of hash lookups.

Comment: Totally redundant might be a bit harsh, hash lookups are more expensive than accessing a reference. It all depends on the context.

Comment: Good points... Feel free to down-vote if you think it is a bad practice ;)

Comment: I reread this answer. If you are going to cache, cache the values of `isWindows`, `isUnix`, etc. That way you save on the string comparison time also.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I agree (I didn't remember this 6.5+ years old answer). Could you edit it accordingly?

Comment: @Brian True. I have edited this very old answer accordingly, to refer to the more recent one.

Comment: In the days of Windows 10 you can imagine why this was a bad practice. Please do not `if(getOsName().startsWith("Windows 9")) { /* 95 and 98 */ } else { }`

Answer (score 57):

some of the links in the answers above seem to be broken. I have added pointers to current source code in the code below and offer an approach for handling the check with an enum as an answer so that a switch statement can be used when evaluating the result:

```
OsCheck.OSType ostype=OsCheck.getOperatingSystemType();
switch (ostype) {
    case Windows: break;
    case MacOS: break;
    case Linux: break;
    case Other: break;
}
```

The helper class is:

```
/**
 * helper class to check the operating system this Java VM runs in
 *
 * please keep the notes below as a pseudo-license
 *
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java
 * compare to http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/tc/dso/tags/2.6.4/code/base/common/src/com/tc/util/runtime/Os.java
 * http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/lang/SystemUtils.java.html
 */
import java.util.Locale;
public static final class OsCheck {
  /**
   * types of Operating Systems
   */
  public enum OSType {
    Windows, MacOS, Linux, Other
  };

  // cached result of OS detection
  protected static OSType detectedOS;

  /**
   * detect the operating system from the os.name System property and cache
   * the result
   * 
   * @returns - the operating system detected
   */
  public static OSType getOperatingSystemType() {
    if (detectedOS == null) {
      String OS = System.getProperty("os.name", "generic").toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
      if ((OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0) || (OS.indexOf("darwin") >= 0)) {
        detectedOS = OSType.MacOS;
      } else if (OS.indexOf("win") >= 0) {
        detectedOS = OSType.Windows;
      } else if (OS.indexOf("nux") >= 0) {
        detectedOS = OSType.Linux;
      } else {
        detectedOS = OSType.Other;
      }
    }
    return detectedOS;
  }
}
```

Comment: (OS.indexOf("darwin") >= 0) can never be true because it comes after (OS.indexOf("win") >= 0)

Comment: The code above *may* have locale issues, since it uses toLowerCase(), which is locale sensitive.  Where this matters is particularly when converting i's to lower/upper case, since in Turkey, I becomes lower case undotted i (ı), and i becomes upper case dotted i (İ).  So "WINDOWS".toLowerCase().indexOf("win") will return -1 in Turkey. Always pass a locale when doing a lower case of a particular language, ie "WINDOWS".toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).indexOf("win") will work in Turkey.

Answer (score 48):

**TL;DR**

For accessing OS use: `System.getProperty("os.name")`.

---

### But  WAIT!!!

Why not create a utility class, make it reusable! And probably much faster on multiple calls. **Clean, clear, faster!**

Create a Util class for such utility functions. Then create public enums for each operating system type.

```
public class Util {     
        public enum OS {
            WINDOWS, LINUX, MAC, SOLARIS
        };// Operating systems.

    private static OS os = null;

    public static OS getOS() {
        if (os == null) {
            String operSys = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
            if (operSys.contains("win")) {
                os = OS.WINDOWS;
            } else if (operSys.contains("nix") || operSys.contains("nux")
                    || operSys.contains("aix")) {
                os = OS.LINUX;
            } else if (operSys.contains("mac")) {
                os = OS.MAC;
            } else if (operSys.contains("sunos")) {
                os = OS.SOLARIS;
            }
        }
        return os;
    }
}
```

Now, you can easily invoke class from any class as follows,(P.S. Since we declared os variable as static, it will consume time only once to identify the system type, then it can be used until your application halts. )

```
            switch (Util.getOS()) {
            case WINDOWS:
                //do windows stuff
                break;
            case LINUX:
```

and That is it!

Comment: I want to use this piece of code in an open-source project (https://github.com/openhab/openhab-addons), is this okay with you?

Comment: Yes please feel free to use it.

Comment: Why? It's not cleaner or clearer, and I doubt it's really much faster, either.

Comment: Go ahead and put rationale for why you said so. I am happy to change the code if you have any reasonable evidence... Be reasonable and clarify your comment please, so that I can improve my 7-8 years old answer...

Answer (score 48):

The following JavaFX classes have static methods to determine current OS (isWindows(),isLinux()...):

- com.sun.javafx.PlatformUtil
- com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.HostUtils
- com.sun.javafx.util.Utils

Example:

```
if (PlatformUtil.isWindows()){
           ...
}
```

Comment: Please note that the access to "com/sun/javafx/*" is discouraged now (checked it with JDK 1.8.0_121).

Comment: @MichaelMarton Have a reference for your statement?

Comment: @HummelingEngineeringBV: I guess it was a mistake from my side. I am working with eclipse Neon 4.6.3 and the "Java Build Path" shows several "Discouraged: com/sun/javafx/**" warnings. However, as I found out, this happens to be an eclipse-bug and/or -feature (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743027/eclipse-gives-warning-on-access-restriction-for-jfxrt-jar-classes)).

Comment: I have to correct myself one more time. Beginning with Java 9/10+, several "com.sun.*" packages/APIs are about to be removed. Check out [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F7696E02-A1FB-4D5A-B1F2-89E7007D4096) for more info. I actually stumbled over this because we use some of these packages. Migrating to eclipse 4.8/JDK 10, we now have to fix these and several other compiler errors due to missing references.

Answer (score 18):

A small example of what you're trying to achieve would probably be a `class` similar to what's underneath:

```java
import java.util.Locale;

public class OperatingSystem
{
    private static String OS = System.getProperty("os.name", "unknown").toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);

    public static boolean isWindows()
    {
        return OS.contains("win");
    }

    public static boolean isMac()
    {
        return OS.contains("mac");
    }

    public static boolean isUnix()
    {
        return OS.contains("nux");
    }
}
```

This particular implementation is quite reliable and should be universally applicable. Just copy and paste it into your `class` of choice.

Comment: Why make it so complicated? System.getProperty("os.name") is sufficient. Don't bother with the  unnecessary fluff.

Answer (score 12):

Try this,simple and easy

```
System.getProperty("os.name");
System.getProperty("os.version");
System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're interested in how an open source project does stuff like this, you can check out the Terracotta class (Os.java) that handles this junk here:

- <strike>http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/tc/dso/trunk/code/base/common/src/com/tc/util/runtime/</strike>
- http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/tc/dso/tags/2.6.4/code/base/common/src/com/tc/util/runtime/

And you can see a similar class to handle JVM versions (Vm.java and VmVersion.java) here:

- http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/tc/dso/trunk/common/src/main/java/com/tc/util/runtime/

Comment: That Terracotta class is pretty comprehensive!

Comment: also suffers from the same issue identified by James Roper in [Wolfgang Fahl's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18417382/814422) -- use of `toLowerCase` without specifying a locale

Answer (score 10):

**If you're working in a security sensitive environment, then please read this through.**

Please refrain from ever trusting a property obtained via the `System#getProperty(String)` subroutine! Actually, almost every property including `os.arch`, `os.name`, and `os.version` isn't readonly as you'd might expect — instead, they're actually quite the opposite.

First of all, any code with sufficient permission of invoking the `System#setProperty(String, String)` subroutine can modify the returned literal at will. However, that's not necessarily the primary issue here, as it can be resolved through the use of a so called `SecurityManager`, as described in greater detail over [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html).

The actual issue is that any user is able to edit these properties when running the `JAR` in question (through `-Dos.name=`, `-Dos.arch=`, etc.). A possible way to avoid tampering with the application parameters is by querying the `RuntimeMXBean` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1531999/11173058). The following code snippet should provide some insight into how this may be achieved.

```java
RuntimeMXBean runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
List<String> arguments = runtimeMxBean.getInputArguments();

for (String argument : arguments) {
    if (argument.startsWith("-Dos.name") {
        // System.getProperty("os.name") altered
    } else if (argument.startsWith("-Dos.arch") {
        // System.getProperty("os.arch") altered
    }
}
```

Comment: File.separator does not look like a serious solution. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Yes! There actually is quite an elegant way of detecting tampering with the system properties. I'll update the answer accordingly. But please be aware that a check can only do so much - if a person has physical access to your application, it **will be possible** to break it - no matter how sophisticated the check.

Answer (score 9):

Below code shows the values that you can get from System API, these all things you can get through this API.

```
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        //Operating system name
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));

        //Operating system version
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.version"));

        //Path separator character used in java.class.path
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("path.separator"));

        //User working directory
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

        //User home directory
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));

        //User account name
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.name"));

        //Operating system architecture
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.arch"));

        //Sequence used by operating system to separate lines in text files
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version")); //JRE version number

        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vendor.url")); //JRE vendor URL

        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vendor")); //JRE vendor name

        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home")); //Installation directory for Java Runtime Environment (JRE)

        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));

        System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.separator"));
    }
}
```

Answers:-

```
Windows 7
6.1
;
C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace-eclipse\JavaExample
C:\Users\user
user
amd64


1.7.0_71
http://java.oracle.com/
Oracle Corporation
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace-Eclipse\JavaExample\target\classes
\
```

Answer (score 9):

I think following can give broader coverage in fewer lines

```
import org.apache.commons.exec.OS;

if (OS.isFamilyWindows()){
                //load some property
            }
else if (OS.isFamilyUnix()){
                //load some other property
            }
```

More details here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/OS.html

Answer (score 7):

A bit shorter, cleaner (and eagerly computed) version of the top answers:

```
switch(OSType.DETECTED){
...
}
```

The helper enum:

```
public enum OSType {
    Windows, MacOS, Linux, Other;
    public static final  OSType DETECTED;
    static{
        String OS = System.getProperty("os.name", "generic").toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        if ((OS.contains("mac")) || (OS.contains("darwin"))) {
            DETECTED = OSType.MacOS;
        } else if (OS.contains("win")) {
            DETECTED = OSType.Windows;
        } else if (OS.contains("nux")) {
            DETECTED = OSType.Linux;
        } else {
            DETECTED = OSType.Other;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is just System.getProperty("os.name"). Nobody wants to do all this extra work.  Why bother?

Answer (score 6):

I find that the [OS Utils from Swingx](https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/swingx/blob/master/swingx-common/src/main/java/org/jdesktop/swingx/util/OS.java) does the job.

Comment: The above link seems to be broken, probably due to SwingX introducing branches; the 1.6 release is here: https://swingx.dev.java.net/source/browse/swingx/tags/SwingX-1-6/src/java/org/jdesktop/swingx/util/OS.java?view=markup

Comment: @David Moles, thanks. the link was ok when I answered- I've now updated it with your one.

Comment: Latest version is here: http://java.net/projects/swingx/sources/svn/content/trunk/swingx-core/src/main/java/org/jdesktop/swingx/util/Utilities.java

Comment: Oracle shut down the java.net site, so Someone who cares should edit this answer to fix the link.

Comment: I found a version here https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/swingx/blob/master/swingx-common/src/main/java/org/jdesktop/swingx/util/OS.java - thanks @MarkHu for notifying the broken link

Answer (score 5):

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
System.out.println("Operating system " + osName);
```

Answer (score 3):

I liked Wolfgang's answer, just because I believe things like that should be consts...

so I've rephrased it a bit for myself, and thought to share it :)

```
/**
 * types of Operating Systems
 *
 * please keep the note below as a pseudo-license
 *
 * helper class to check the operating system this Java VM runs in
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java
 * compare to http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/tc/dso/tags/2.6.4/code/base/common/src/com/tc/util/runtime/Os.java
 * http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/lang/SystemUtils.java.html
 */
public enum OSType {
    MacOS("mac", "darwin"),
    Windows("win"),
    Linux("nux"),
    Other("generic");

    private static OSType detectedOS;

    private final String[] keys;

    private OSType(String... keys) {
        this.keys = keys;
    }

    private boolean match(String osKey) {
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            if (osKey.indexOf(keys[i]) != -1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static OSType getOS_Type() {
        if (detectedOS == null)
            detectedOS = getOperatingSystemType(System.getProperty("os.name", Other.keys[0]).toLowerCase());
        return detectedOS;
    }

    private static OSType getOperatingSystemType(String osKey) {
        for (OSType osType : values()) {
            if (osType.match(osKey))
                return osType;
        }
        return Other;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like "darwin" can never be matched because checking "win" would already cause Windows to be returned.

Comment: see fix in my original answer

Comment: Congratulations, you've reimplemented sun.awt.OSInfo#getOSType :)

Comment: HHHHH... good one... @Kirill Gamazkov I didn't find it back then.. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 3):

You can just use sun.awt.OSInfo#getOSType() method

Comment: This should be the best answer! I was just checking if someone already has mentioned this over here.

Comment: Any workaround for this being 'restricted API'? I'd like to try using this but it gives me that warning in Eclipse. I can use an older jre (e.g. jre1.8.0_171), but the latest 1.8 jres have it marked as restricted.

Comment: Whole 'sun' package is deprecated, I can't imagine how one could workaround this. Seems that it's just `System.getProperty("os.name")` and then checks if the property contains 'Windows', 'Linux', 'Solaris' or 'OS X', so it's basically the same as Vishal Chaudhari's answer

Answer (score 2):

This code for displaying all information about the system os type,name , java information and so on.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Properties pro = System.getProperties();
    for(Object obj : pro.keySet()){
        System.out.println(" System  "+(String)obj+"     :  "+System.getProperty((String)obj));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In com.sun.jna.Platform class you can find useful static methods like

```
Platform.isWindows();
Platform.is64Bit();
Platform.isIntel();
Platform.isARM();
```

and much more.

If you use Maven just add dependency

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
 <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
 <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise just find jna library jar file (ex. jna-5.2.0.jar) and add it to classpath.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `com.sun.javafx.util.Utils` as below.

```
if ( Utils.isWindows()){
     // LOGIC HERE
}
```

**OR USE**

```
boolean isWindows = OSInfo.getOSType().equals(OSInfo.OSType.WINDOWS);
       if (isWindows){
         // YOUR LOGIC HERE
       }
```

Answer (score -1):

Since google points "kotlin os name" to this page, here's the Kotlin version of @Memin 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31547504/536226):

```
private var _osType: OsTypes? = null
val osType: OsTypes
    get() {
        if (_osType == null) {
            _osType = with(System.getProperty("os.name").lowercase(Locale.getDefault())) {
                if (contains("win"))
                    OsTypes.WINDOWS
                else if (listOf("nix", "nux", "aix").any { contains(it) })
                    OsTypes.LINUX
                else if (contains("mac"))
                    OsTypes.MAC
                else if (contains("sunos"))
                    OsTypes.SOLARIS
                else
                    OsTypes.OTHER
            }
        }
        return _osType!!
    }

enum class OsTypes {
    WINDOWS, LINUX, MAC, SOLARIS, OTHER
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For getting OS name, simply use:

```
Platform.getOS()
```

Lets say you want to see if platform is linux:

```
if (Platform.getOS().equals(Platform.OS_LINUX)) {
}
```

Similarly Platform class have defined constants for others operating system names. Platform class is part of `org.eclipse.core.runtime` package.

Comment: Which package / jar contains this class?

Comment: `org.eclipse.core.runtime`