# How to find the JMX port in a server?

Tags: java, jboss, jmx

I am sure I can figure it out if I can see the JAVA OPTS parameters. I want to monitor a hornetq server using Jconsole, so I need the port number.

I remember using some command like java grep etc when I connected to it a while back.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you know the process number you can use [netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) to find what ports the program is listening on with something like

```
$ netstat -apn | grep <proc num>
```

The conventional port for JMX listeners is 1099.

Answer (score 14):

I know it's an old post.  You can also get the details from System:

```
String jmx1 = System.getProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote");
String jmx2 = System.getProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.port");
String jmx3 = System.getProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate");
String jmx4 = System.getProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl");
String jmx5 = System.getProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also manually set the port from the JVM commandline settings, e.g:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1616
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [programmatically access the JVM arguments like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application/1531999#1531999):

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean;
...       
RuntimeMXBean RuntimemxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
List<String> arguments = RuntimemxBean.getInputArguments();
```