# trying to view stack of unresponsive JVM : both jvisualvm and jconsole fail to connect

Tags: jvm, jconsole, jvisualvm

I have a Java program on my local machine that becomes unresponsive after sometime and appears to freeze without making further progress. I guess it blocks somewhere (it is accessing remote resources over both HTTP and JDBC so a blocking situation is likely). I am trying to connect to it to see a view of the main thread's stack so as to understand where the block occurred. Both `jvisualvm` and `jconsole` list the JVM in question (among others running in my system) but both fail to connect.

`jconsole` balks with "connection failed" (even when I try the insecure option).

`jvisualvm` appears to connect but when I hit the 'sampler' tab to see the stack it complains with the screenshot below:

[image]

The thing is I am using the same utilities (`jconsole` and `jvisualvm`) to connect to other JVMs in my system which I have invoked without using any of the JMX options mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10368260/274677) and I don't have any issues. How can I get the stack of this unresponsive JVM to see where it blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced a similar issue today with a JVM that was completely stuck and I was unable to properly attach jconsole/jvisualvm to it. Also `kill -3 <PID>` was unsuccessful (no Thread dump).

I was able to trigger a coredump of the JVM using `kill -11 <PID>` and feed that into jstack as follows: `jstack /path/to/java /path/to/core.file`. From the jstack output I was able to extract some useful stack information.

Comment: kill -11 initially responded with "*Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again*". After running **ulimit** the core was produced.

Answer (score 2):

You could just **collect a thread dump** with `kill -3 <PID>`.

This will show you all the threads and where they are blocked.

Comment: Wouldn't that show the stack of the JVM code instead? I am interested in the threads of the Java code that gets interpreted by the JVM.

Comment: This would show all the threads in the VM, the application and the system threads and their states. You can then see where your threads are blocking.

Comment: OK, both -3 and -11 worked in my case. I am accepting the other answer as it also mentioned the *jstack* tool