# Is there a Java API to get the VM arguments?

Tags: java, api, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get vm arguments from inside of java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application)

I want print the current command line options of a Java process in a log file. Is there an API in Java to request this parameters? I does not means the program arguments that are passed to main. I am interesting on the -X and -D parameters.

Comment: Those are VM arguments, not program arguments.  You might be able to find them in a properties file somewhere, but that's the best I've got, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This method will give you all the command line arguments [RuntimeMXBean.getInputArguments()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getInputArguments%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can get passed system properties (-D flag) using System.getProperty(String property). 
If you use this method you must provide property name, if you would like to get all the properties just use System.getProperties().