# JVM options : what values are passed?

Tags: java, jvm

I am using commadline java and javac on my Ubuntu Linux host and I was wondering how can I get the list and values of options being  passed to JVM like -Xmx -Xms -Xss ?

Also I could not find this information on `man java` or `man javac` and I was very surprised with that. Can you help?

Comment: This answer is what you are looking for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are asking what are the possible command line options and their potential values.

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) is the man page 
for the Solaris/Linux version of the JVM.

The general page for links to documentation of the OS-specific versions of all the tools is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/index.html).

Comment: Also while my program is running how can I know what options JVM is operating with. Like what is the Heap Size or Stack Size my code started running with ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access this information at runtime, you can use the JMX management beans, specifically  [RuntimeMXBean.getInputArguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getInputArguments%28%29).  Additionally, many of the values are available from the relevant beans, e.g. the [current heap memory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html#getHeapMemoryUsage%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

A quick look:
[Javac options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html) (it may be for 1.5 but it is still true for the latest JRE/JDK ) 
[JRE default options in Linux/Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/java.html) which was originally found in [Java Hotspot VM options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) (see the section **Categories of Java HotSpot VM Options** ).

Hope this helps!