# How can I return the command which Eclipse uses to execute my main method?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have built a main method in a class within a huge project which has a large amount of dependencies both from maven and as external jars. Using the built-in run feature in Eclipse makes the main method execute as wished, but now I would like to create a run.sh script that executes the main method. Because of the complexity of the java command, I would very much hope there is a way to actually export the command which Eclipse uses for the execution instead of having to manually build it from scratch. Is this possible?

Comment: This may help you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it from the debug perspective. Execute your application, switch to debug perspective, right click on the `javaw.exe` or `java.exe` under your application and and select `Properties`. This will popup `Process properties` dialog that contains the `Command Line` used for its execution.

[image]