# Is there a way to determine size of the old region of the heap in runtime

Tags: java

Size of the old region is controlled using -XX:NewRatio parameter, how would I determine its value in runtime?
Thanks in advance!

Update
I haven't been attentive enough, the question is basically a copy of [How to get vm arguments from inside of java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application). I would delete it but there is an interesting discussion below so I will do it a little bit later when it is finished

Comment: Side question: why do you want to know?

Comment: I want to know how much memory I have for an int array. As far as I know big arrays are allocated directly in the old region

Comment: And what if you don't have the required size? What is supposed to happen in this case? How large is this potential array so that you need this information?

Comment: I'm trying to implement external sorting for ints file, heap size is restricted. I argee that this is not a good job for java but that is what they want from me) This potential array should be as large as possible in order to sort as much as possible ints at once

Comment: Then why don't use use a mapped file?

Comment: OK, let me restate the problem; you have a large file full of int values; are they binary representation of ints? If yes, what endianness? Or is it something else?

Comment: I dont fully understand, probably because I'm not good in IO. By mapped file you mean MappedByteBuffer, is that correct?

Comment: You're right, endianness is big-endian

Comment: And how large is that file exactly?

Comment: Oh, _very_ important: are these ints signed or unsigned?

Comment: It's a few GB large and heap size is a few MB, ints are signed

Comment: Other question: do you use Java 7?

Comment: Uhm, wait, there are limitations to `FileChannel.map()` which you should be aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so, if I understand correctly, you have a *very* large file, several GB large, full of ints, and these ints are stored in big endian.

My proposal is the following: create a class implementing `List<Integer>` over such a large file, and use `Collections.sort()`.

That is:

- you take as an argument the file you need sorted;
- you map that file in memory;
- you implement the `List` interface;
- you let `Collections.sort()` do the job.

Once `Collections.sort()` is done, you just `.force()` the channel from which you obtained the `MappedByteBuffer`. If no I/O error, you're good to go, replace the original file.

Yeah, that is quite some work, but it is doable. Demo code on demand.

NOTE: `FileChannel.map()` is limited; you may have to create several mappings. I'd recommend splitting into 1 GB mappings. This will quite complicate the implementation of `.subList()`, admittedly. Also, be aware that you'll only be able to address up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` ints; which means your file cannot be larger than `((1 << 31 - 1) << 2)`. 1 << 33 is 8 GB.

Comment: You'll have to benchmark it though. This largely requires OS support for mapping. Also, as I said, beware of `.subList()`, this may require quite some work! But it is doable nevertheless. Now, maybe there is a better solution, but out of my head I don't know of any.