# Get jre command line arguments

Tags: java, jvm

considering the following command

```
java -Xmx1024M -jar app.jar arg0 arg1
```

The question is, how could I get the java input arguments here? I mean how could I get the `-Xmx1024M`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Answered question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application

Comment: Do you need to get these arguments from code or command line?

Comment: @JakubK yes dude, I want to halt the application if `-Xmx` argument hasn't set, another question, is it possible to increase the heap memory size during runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list arguments by using [RuntimeMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html):

```
List<String> arguments = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments();
```

Unfortunately it's not possible to change java heap size limits at runtime

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is ensure that your application has sufficient memory, you can use the `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` or `Runtime.getRunetime.totalmemory()` methods, depending on your needs.