# Retrieve JVM Parameter in Java Bean without cycling on all values

Tags: java, jvm, log4j, javabeans

is there a faster way to retrieve a JVM Parameter in a Java Bean?

I've read about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application):

RuntimeMXBean runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
List arguments = runtimeMxBean.getInputArguments();

but then you have to cycle on all the parameters...I think it's not so good.

For example in log4j properties you can retrieve the parameter using this notation: ${MY_JVM_PARAMETER}. Is there a similar think available in Java code?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and trivial way is to use the `java.lang.System#getProperty`:

```
String prop = System.getProperty("my.property");
```

Assuming that you lanched your java application with a jvm param like `-Dmy.property="someValue"`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, it returns me a null value. And yes, I've used -Dmyproperty=someValue. I'm noticing that someValue is not between quotes, it could be that?

Comment: Nice to hear that and maybe you can paste the tecik so it is made viewble for others, what was the problem already?