# Get the JVMs compiler-threshold during runtime

Tags: java, jit

Is it possible to get the current value of the JVMs CompileThreshold during runtime?

If it was set manually I can get it form the [VM Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application%20Get%20VM%20Arguments). Otherwise I may assume default values (e.g. 10,000 for Oracles HotSpot on Servers), but this might not be correct. Is there are better way?

The purpose is to "preheat" some functions during startup.

Comment: You can call the functions with appropriate parameters to pre-compile it. But the function may be recompiled later depending on call parameters. "preheat" is only useful for benchmarking. You should avoid all the magic for a normal application. It may complicate the code and dependencies but does not really improve the applications performance.

Comment: Hi @Konrad. Your guess is correct: It's for a toolbox that should help to measure performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrive this information from the `HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean`.

```
static final String HOTSPOT_BEAN_NAME = "com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class clazz = Class.forName("com.sun.management.HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean");
    MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean bean = (HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean) ManagementFactory
            .newPlatformMXBeanProxy(server, HOTSPOT_BEAN_NAME, clazz);
    VMOption vmOption = bean.getVMOption("CompileThreshold");
    System.out.printf("%s = %s%n", vmOption.getName(), vmOption.getValue());
}
```

**output**

```
CompileThreshold = 10000
```

Comment: Is there also a way that is more JVM-independent? This seems to work only on Hotspot.

Comment: @MyPasswordIsLasercats I would not assume it. As `CompileThreshold` itself is already JVM (Oracle, OpenJDK) dependent.