# Is there any way to programmatically check, if `-noverify` is set on the JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I need to run some Tests with the VM-option `-noverify`.
Now I would like to warn any other developer in this project to set this option, if not already done.

Another possible solution would be, of course, to set this option instead of just warn about it.

Comment: Hope this will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application

Comment: You are right, that was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The java.lang.System.getProperties() method determines the current system properties. The current set of system properties for use by the getProperty(String) method is returned as a Properties object.

Run this program

```
public class ShowSystemProps {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   // Get the current system properties
   Properties p = System.getProperties();
   p.list(System.out);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, the vm arguments aren't listed in the system properties.
@Ravis Comment holds the solution