# How do I extend/append a variable like MAVEN_OPTS in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We are using GitLab Enterprise Edition 13.12.2-ee on a company-provided Dockermachine runner to build Maven-based projects. They set MAVEN_OPTS to contain environment-specific parameters like Proxy settings.
For our build, we need to append MAVEN_OPTS, for example to set -Dmaven.repo.local to enable caching of our local Maven repository.
I tried several variants for this in our .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
build:
  variables:
    MAVEN_OPTS: $MAVEN_OPTS "-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository"
    MAVEN_OPTS: "$MAVEN_OPTS -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository"
    MAVEN_OPTS: ${MAVEN_OPTS} "-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository"
    MAVEN_OPTS: "${MAVEN_OPTS} -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository"
    MAVEN_OPTS: $$MAVEN_OPTS "-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository"
    MAVEN_OPTS: "$$MAVEN_OPTS -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository"
```

Of course only one at a time, not all at once. None of them seems to work. Does anyone have a hint, how to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried `MAVEN_OPTS: '-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository'`?

Comment: Sure. This overrides the whole MAVEN_OPTS which is not what I want since I lose the aforementioned parameters like proxy settings.

Comment: ok, but then you could just add additional maven options and not overwrite them at all: `build: variables: ADD_MVN_OPTS: '-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository'`

and run maven like:
`script: - mvn $MAVEN_OPTS $ADD_MVN_OPTS clean install`

Comment: No. These would be parameters for the Maven application itself. But MAVEN_OPTS are JVM parameters, so these are some kind of lower level. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955721/maven-opts-vs-mvn-d