# How do I detect from my application that it was started with JProfiler?

Tags: java, jprofiler

I know that I "shouldn't do this", but I fiddle with the ClassLoaders a bit and JProfiler doesn't like that and it hasn't to do anything with what I want to profile, so just stick to the question, please :).

How do I detect from my application that it was started with JProfiler? Or maybe just that JProfiler is currently connected?

Comment: You can inspect command line arguments (Not those you get in `main` method) and search for "agent".

Comment: Oookay. How do I get those? Do I need native Code die that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application for how to get the VM parameters. JProfiler should not interfere with your classloaders, what problem do you experience?

Comment: I don't know. I asked this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727323/get-all-command-line-option

Comment: @IngoKegel: Thanks for that, that worked out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple if you know how:

```
public static boolean isStartedWithJProfiler() {
    RuntimeMXBean runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
    List<String> arguments = runtimeMxBean.getInputArguments();
    for( String argument : arguments ) {
        if( argument.contains("profilerti") ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```