# How to read the value passed with -javaagent at runtime?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I need to read the value of the parameter `-javaagent` at runtime. How do I access this value programmatically?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but your question is covered by [this more general question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application) (and the groovy version is more concise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using the JVM's `RuntimeMXBean`:

```
prefix = '-javaagent:'
javaAgentValue = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.runtimeMXBean.inputArguments.find{ it.startsWith(prefix)} ?.substring(prefix.size())
```