# how to substring characters from string in java

Tags: java, string, substring

I have below line -

> lax.nl.java.option.additional=-Xms1000m -Xmx**2048**m -Xss2m
>   -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Djava.library.path=native   -Djava.security.auth.login.config==login_configuration.config

And i want to extract the Xmx value i.e. 2048 in this case (It can also be 512 some times). Not sure how i should do this using java substring or any other way , Please help! .
Thanks

Comment: thatLine.split("Xmx")[1].split("m")[0]

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to match the `m` as well? What if somebody specifies `-Xmx2G`?

Comment: The context is **the line** @Henry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get vm arguments from inside of java application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application)

Comment: @Spiderman my comment was directed to the OP.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Don't see how this is a dup?

Comment: Do you want to match that out of the string? Or do you want the maximum memory from the currently running VM?

Additionally, the ending of that number can vary. 

-Xms

The -Xms option sets the initial and minimum Java heap size. The Java heap (the “heap”) is the part of the memory where blocks of memory are allocated to objects and freed during garbage collection.

Note: -Xms does not limit the total amount of memory that the JVM can use.
Operation

Format: -Xms<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]

Combine -Xms with a memory value and ad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment given by @Spiderman might be a quick one line solution.  But in general the way to approach this type of regex problem in Java is to use a `Pattern` with a `Matcher`.  The following regex can be used here:

```
.*\s-Xmx(\d+)(\w+)\s.*
```

**Full code:**

```
String line = "lax.nl.java.option.additional=-Xms1000m -Xmx2048m -Xss2m -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Djava.library.path=native -Djava.security.auth.login.config==login_configuration.config";

String pattern = ".*\\s-Xmx(\\d+)(\\w+)\\s.*";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("Found unit: " +  m.group(2));
}
```

**Output:**

```
Found value: 2048
Found unit: m
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. But beginners will definitely prefer split method over regex. But regex is far more better solution than split. Thanks

Comment: Downvoter is someone who has done -1 to me as well. :) . FYI, I am the upvoter

Comment: this is a jvm arguments string, at minimum an accepted answer should be able to deal with multiple endings for the units.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html

Format: -Xms<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Let's wait for feedback from the OP.  We don't want to overengineer something which isn't needed here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'd sooner not have a newbie have a bug lying in wait, as well as being an incorrect answer sitting at the top of google.

Comment: Thanks Tim, reversed my -1.

Comment: This solution is probably good enough, but there are still cases where it fails (this always happens if one does not do the "right thing" according to specification), e.g. `-Dparam=xxx-Xmx2048m`

Comment: @Henry No, my solution would actually still run in this case, q.v. [here](http://rextester.com/RXVT92031).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it matches the wrong value in a string like this ` -Xmx2048m -D=x-Xmx7m`

Answer (score 0):

Also this can be done without using Regex. Simply use [**`split()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method as below:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "lax.nl.java.option.additional=-Xms1000m -Xmx2048m -Xss2m -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Djava.library.path=native -Djava.security.auth.login.config==login_configuration.config";
        String number = line.split("Xmx")[1].split("m")[0];
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a jvm arguments string, at minimum an accepted answer should be able to deal with multiple endings for the units.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html

Format: -Xms<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]