# How to set environment variable in Java without 'illegal reflective access'? How to use add-opens?

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, environment-variables

Long story short, I have to set an environment during runtime for a specific test.

The answers here on SO work fine, I am using [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/496849/4420543). The problem is I am getting this warning:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by **YOUR PACKAGE** (file: **YOUR FILE** ) to field java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.m
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of **YOUR PACKAGE**
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

I've started searching for a solution and the [other SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35393623/4420543) that 'solves' the problem with the unit tests uses the same method for setting the environment variable.

I am talking about [this line of code](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-rules/blob/b319ac4a9ed349ae1887cd6634332ed8cd8f965c/src/main/java/org/junit/contrib/java/lang/system/EnvironmentVariables.java#L188) from their Github source, which triggers this error.
(`field.setAccessible(true);`)

So it looks like there is no other way to solve it, other than setting the given flag, just as the warning suggest.

Then I was wondering if this warning is severe at all and if my program is going to run at all in a couple months (I am using OpenJDK 11). It [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53800916/4420543) this `illegal-access` setting will be removed in future release.

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE):

> If you must continue to use a component that requires illegal access, then you can eliminate the warning messages by using one or more --add-opens options to open only those internal packages to which access is required.

Then later:

> To verify that your application is ready for a future version of the JDK, run it with --illegal-access=deny along with any necessary --add-opens options.

Then I started to look for the syntax `--add-opens` needs and could not find how to use it properly.

I could find this, but I still don't understand how to use it in a Kotlin project and what the name of the modules are.

> --add-opens module/package=target-module(,target-module)*/
>
> Updates module to open package to target-module, regardless of module declaration.

How do use `--add-opens` to enable modification to `java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.m`? Can I just enable add-opens to this only field or do I need to enable it to entire `java.util.Collection`? Is that reasonable?

Actually, I am only writing this entire question out like this, because there may be something wrong in the process that I am doing in a not-intended way.

Thanks for help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-7BB28E4D-99B3-4078-BDC4-FC24180CE82B) for `--add-opens` you've already cited above, you only could open modules on package level:

```
--add-opens module/package=target-module(,target-module)*
```

Since `java.util.Collections` belongs to the `java.util` package from the [`java.base` module](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html), you have to add the JVM argument

```
--add-opens java.base/java.util=target-module(,target-module)*
```

where your target modules must be the modules that want to access `java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.m`, or `ALL-UNNAMED` modules.

```
--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Answer (score 0):

System Stubs v2.0.0 now provides a solution for this using Mockito.

https://github.com/webcompere/system-stubs

It can be used standalone:

```java
new EnvironmentVariables("SET_THIS_VAR", "toThis")
   .execute(() -> runThisCode());
```

Or has a JUnit 5 plug in.

The `EnvironmentVariableMocker` in its core project could also be used stand-alone if required.