# Azure CI-CD Android : Unable to start the daemon process. Error: The process '/Users/runner/work/1/s/gradlew' failed with exit code

Tags: android, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, cicd

My project is flavour based QA, UAT, PROD.
In local system everything works well build apk generation successfully.
But with Azure I'm facing [image: Pipeline]

[image: pipeline1]

I have tried editing pipeline steps. But didn't work.Also checked JDK version.
But I'm not sure if anything need to do for different environment/flavour.
Thanks in Adavance. Your response will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

**In the log you will find the following lines:**

```
Unable to start the daemon process.
Error: The process '...' failed with exit code 1`
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option used.
Please refer...
Process command line: ...
Please read the following process output to find out more:
Unrecognized option: --illegal-access=permit
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

**The decisive part:**

```
Unrecognized option: --illegal-access=permit
```

Please check your pipeline, environment (variables) and project if the parameter is set there.

E.g. by DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS.

Please check your Java version. Is the same JVM version used in the local and Azure build? In Java 8 this parameter did not exist yet. It was introduced with Java 9.

---

For more information about `--illegal-access` click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53800916/22373734).