# How can I programmatically determine the setting of jdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth

Tags: java, ntlm

I have a case where the server I am working on must be able to use NTLM authentication.
I believe it is setting:

```
jdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth=allHosts
```

But I want to prove that at run time.
That value is set in a special place.  From inside where Java is installed in my case the file is here:

```
C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.4.11-hotspot\conf\net.properties
```

How can I query that value?
I would like to be able to do it from a debugger in an Evaluate, while paused at a break point.
Something like the following would be good (but note that this doesn't work, since it isn't part of the env)

```
System.getenv("Path")
```

Comment: System.getProperty("jdk.http.....")

Comment: I am assuming this "jdk" property is stored in an alternate store.  It doesn't show up using System.getProperties() nor when using System.getProperty.  Note that I have a server where it is working, and used that to verify it cannot be seen those ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that caches these values is [`java.base/sun.net.NetProperties`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk11u/file/ebc6c83bfa9e/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/net/NetProperties.java#l91) and the `.get(String key)` method is `public static` so it should be accessible to a debugger.

Comment: Great, I was able to evaluate this in IDEA at a breakpoint and see it:   `sun.net.NetProperties.get("jdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth")`

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4247076/5645656) I would say the solution is as follows:

```
System.getProperty("jdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth");
```

Comment: Nice try, seemed like a good one - but sadly didn't work.  I guess it is stored elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned on a working system, where that value is set, that call did not show its value.

Comment: The first lines of net.properties say (emphasis added) "These values are only used when the system properties are _not_ [set]" so it's impossible for them to be system properties.