# PosixFilePermission causing UnsupportedOperationException in java

Tags: java, unix, posix

I have a java code deployed in windows as well as unix system.I have to add file permission for moving the file to a specific directory(in unix).I am using **PosixFilePermission** for this.

```
                file1 = new File( expFilePath+ "/" + creationDate);
                file1.mkdir();
                Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = new HashSet<>();
                perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
                perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
                perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE);
                perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
                perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_WRITE);
                perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_EXECUTE);
                perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
                perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_WRITE);
                perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_EXECUTE);
                try {
                    Files.setPosixFilePermissions(file1.toPath(), perms);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

The above code is running correctly in unix but causing a **UnsupportedOperationException** in windows m/c.I have to manually comment this piece of code while running the code in windows m/c.

Is there any way by which I can detect the underlying os type in java and execute this block of code conditionally?

Comment: If you want to detect the OS, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282498/how-can-i-detect-a-unix-like-os-in-java. Then, if you want to set similar permision in Windows, then here is the link https://www.journaldev.com/855/how-to-set-file-permissions-in-java-easily-using-java-7-posixfilepermission

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `Path` object, you can use the [`Path.getFileSystem()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileSystem--) method to obtain the underlying file system object. It has a [`FileSystem.supportedFileAttributeViews()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#supportedFileAttributeViews--) method. If the file system supports POSIX file attributes (and permissions), the returned set will contain the string `"posix"`.