# How to determine if my app is running on Android

Tags: java, android

I have an app that runs on several mobile devices running either Fedora or Android. To consolidate my codebase and distribution I would like to determine which OS I am on. I tried System.getProperty("os.name"), but that just returns "Linux". Is there something unique to Android in the System properties?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically determine operating system in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228477/608639)

Comment: @jww the "os.name" property is `null` on Android, which most of those answers seem to depend on. The ones that don't rely on Apache Commons, which has no check for Android.

Answer (score 32):

There are several properties you could check. Candidates are:

- java.vendor.url --> http://www.android.com
- java.vm.name --> Dalvik (I don't know, which one Fedora is using...)
- java.vm.vendor --> The Android Project
- java.vendor --> The Android Project

Maybe you want to check by yourself?

```java
Properties p = System.getProperties();
Enumeration keys = p.keys();
while(keys.hasMoreElements()) {
   String key = (String) keys.nextElement();
   String value = (String) p.get(key);
   System.out.println(key + " >>>> " + value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with "java.runtime.name" = "android runtime".

Comment: Hi, This is very helpful indeed. Is there any official word from the Android folks as to which of these will remain invariant? Thanks.

Comment: Shorter: `System.getProperties().list(System.out);`

Comment: @user552447 should be "Android Runtime"

Comment: From Android 5 onward, java.runtime.name returns null. So, it is not reliable.

Answer (score 7):

I do not know Android but if you do not find some unique system property you can sometimes identify the system if some specific class exists there. So you can do the following:

```
boolean isAndroid() {
    try {
        Class.forName("the class name");
        return true;
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 you could look for a class within the android packages. Activity for instance.

Comment: That's also a good idea, but the source may or may not have android.jar.

Comment: This would not work when using a test tool like Robolectrics.

Comment: I'm using this approach with the `android.os.Build` class - which is the class that Android applications are expected to check for different Android platform configurations, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build. So if your application wants to know - not only whether its Android - but also what kind of Android you are running under, then you'd actually want to get a class ref to `Build`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could look for a class that the Android platform does not provide, like `java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer` (since Java 5).

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that I wrote using the information from this page, in case you want to copy-paste:

```
private static YLogger ylogger;
public static YLogger getLogger() {
    if (ylogger == null){
        // need to find a new logger. Let's check if we have Android running
        if (System.getProperty("java.vm.name").equalsIgnoreCase("Dalvik")){
            ylogger = new AndroidLogger();
            ylogger.d("YLoggerFactory", "Instantiating Android-based logger");
        } else {
            // fallback option, system logger.
            ylogger = new SystemLogger();   
            ylogger.d("YLoggerFactory", "Instantiating System-based logger");
        }
    }
    return ylogger;
}
```

Comment: This will probably break with ART.

Comment: Kind of hack but this might help

`boolean isAndroid;
try {
 Class.forName("android.app.Activity");
 isAndroid = true;
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
 isAndroid = false;
}`

Comment: how do you compile this on the backend (without Android libs)? It will fail because of missing AndroidLogger class

Answer (score 2):

The list of defined system properties is here: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System#getProperties()

I'm using

```
boolean android = "The Android Project".equals(System.getProperty("java.specification.vendor"));
```

Comment: this seems like the most stable and quite clear and verbose solution. on a normal/Java.Oracle JVM, this same property returns `"Oracle Corporation"`.

Comment: Java was taken over from SUN by Oracle while Java 6 was the latest version, so at least till Java 5, this would have been a different value.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my processing sketch to determine in which mode I'm running i.e. where I'm running it.

```java
enum Mode {
  java, android
}

Mode getMode() {
  return System.getProperty("java.runtime.name").equals("Android Runtime") ? Mode.android : Mode.java;
}

if (getMode() == Mode.java){
  // do something
  // eg: do something that android can't handle
} else {
  // do android stuff 
  // eg: scale the sketch by 2 to improve visibility
}
```

Comment: You need to use equals() not "==" to compare strings.

Comment: @PeterQuiring Is it like a best practice? "==" works for me.

Comment: It shouldn't work in Java in general. == only compares if the objects are the exact same.  equals() will do a deep comparison of the char arrays.

Comment: It might work by chance if the compiler is de-duplicating strings because both objects would be the same.

Comment: @PeterQuiring I edited it. Thanks for correcting my mistake.