# Are there APIs to check if the system is android, not the desktop jvm?

Tags: java, android, jvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine if my app is running on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519556/how-to-determine-if-my-app-is-running-on-android)

I am going to write a library which will be imported in both desktop and android system.

I would like the library to use different class depending on the system.

I am pretty sure there is a way to check it, but couldn't find.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See if it helps:
[How to determine if my app is running on Android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519556/how-to-determine-if-my-app-is-running-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to look for `android.app.Activity` class through reflection. If it is present - Android system libraries is in your classpath and, thus, you are in Android.

Comment: You would also want to use the Java API if your code is cross platform.