# how to identify whether the OS is Linux desktop or Android?

Tags: java, android

Hi I wanted to know what the OS is pro grammatically  in Android? what i have tried is to get the system property of "os.name". but it returns the value as "Linux". but this does not help. i wanted to know whether it is Android or not? how to do this?

Comment: You want to provide a cross-platform library, I suppose?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519556/how-to-determine-if-my-app-is-running-on-android

Comment: hi on the thread he says he went by "java.runtime.name" = "android runtime".  but i dont find this property anywhere? where is this propert defined,