# Java Preprocessor Check OS

Tags: java, preprocessor, system-properties

How do I use Java preprocessors to determine what OS I am compiling on?

Comment: Uh, what Java preprocessor?

Comment: @James: [spp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/tip/make/tools/src/build/tools/spp/Spp.java), of course! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
System.getProperty("os.name")
```

From [How do I programmatically determine operating system in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java)

BTW Java doesn't have a preprocessor...one of the annoying things I discovered.

Comment: That will return the OS at *runtime*, not compile time.

Comment: Hm...good point...but I guess I was thinking that if you're running the compiler, then chances are you'll know what OS the compiler is running on...

Answer (score 1):

There is no Java preprocessor and no ability to conditionally compile.

There is a very primitive debugging feature built in whereby the compile is allowed to delete conditional blocks with a constant condition which is false to facilitate elimination of debug code - but I don't recall if the spec *requires* or *allows* the code to be deleted from the compiled class.

```
static final boolean DEBUG=false;


...


if(Debugging.DEBUG) {
    // some code which the compile may (or must?) eliminate
    }
```

If you want to detect the O/S at runtime and do different things on different platforms, there are a number of system properties required in every JVM which are documented in `System.getProperties()`.  See the JavaDoc, relative it's installed or network location:

```
api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()
```