# How to test that JRuby script is being run on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, jruby

`RUBY_PLATFORM` is `java` either way.

Normally I can do system checks with `uname` but Windows doesn't have `uname` command. (and checking that `uname` didn't run correctly is pretty silly)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java (relates to JVMs in general, and thus JRuby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'rbconfig'

puts RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, if you need underlying architecture, you can check `RUBY_DESCRIPTION`, and look between `[` and `]`.

```
irb(main):004:0> RUBY_DESCRIPTION
=> "jruby 1.7.0.dev (ruby-1.9.3-p139) (2012-03-30 387d8ad) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_29) [darwin-x86_64-java]"
```