# how to detect OS at run time using java class?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

I make modular App in netbeans platform, and I don't know how to check in which OS this App is running java? accoriding that I want to set the path of my folder and images in my App. and I want to check that  at run time. Please suggest me.

Comment: Check out this topic: How do I programmatically determine operating system in Java?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the NetBeans Platform then you should add a dependency with the [Utilities module](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-util/org/openide/util/Utilities.html) (very useful):

Then you just say

```
Utilities.isMac() or Utilities.isUnix() or Utilities.isWindows().
```

In case you want to do it more precisely you can

```
switch( Utilities.getOperatingSystem() )
{
  case Utilities.OS_AIX: 
  case Utilities.OS_FREEBSD:
  case Utilities.OS_HP:
  case Utilities.OS_IRIX:
  case Utilities.OS_LINUX:
  case Utilities.OS_MAC:
  case Utilities.OS_OPENBSD:
  case Utilities.OS_OS2:
  case Utilities.OS_SOLARIS:
  case Utilities.OS_SUNOS:
  case Utilities.OS_TRU64:
  case Utilities.OS_WIN95:
  case Utilities.OS_WIN98:
  case Utilities.OS_WIN2000:
```

(Well, and all the rest, this is getting too long for an answer, I'm afraid, see the link above for more OSes).

Comment: thank u so much, this method is very nice to detect the OS.

Answer (score 2):

Through:

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
```

You get Os name and you able to compare with your os.For example:

```
boolean isMacOs = osName.startsWith("mac os x"); 
if (isMacOs) 
{
  // do mac-specific things here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this method returns OS name as String

```
System.getProperty("os.name");
```

This class might be of use to start with

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-detect-os-in-java-systemgetpropertyosname/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `System.getProperty("os.name")`.

Answer (score 0):

`System.getProperty("os.name");` should return the OS name.