# How do I get what os the computer is running with java?

Tags: java, operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I programmatically determine operating system in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java)

in Java, how do I get what OS type (Mac, Windows, Linux, etc) that my java applet is being run in?

Thanks in advance ;D

Comment: -1; you should just have asked your favorite search engine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class OpertingSystemInfo 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String nameOS = "os.name";  
    String versionOS = "os.version";  
    String architectureOS = "os.arch";

    System.out.println("\n  The information about OS");
    System.out.println("\nName of the OS: " + System.getProperty(nameOS));
    System.out.println("Version of the OS: " + System.getProperty(versionOS));
    System.out.println("Architecture of THe OS: " + System.getProperty(architectureOS));
  }
}
```

http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/OSInformation.shtml

Comment: Thanks! A nice clear answer :D

Answer (score 3):

The system property [`os.name`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) provides the name of the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(System.getProperties().get("os.name"));
```