# how can I tell in java if the program is running on a windows or linux machine?

Tags: java, linux, windows

Is there a way to tell in Java if the program is running on a Windows or Linux machine?  I have a .jar file that I want to run on both.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this question hasn't been asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go,
[How do I programmatically determine operating system in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228477/2918446)

VonC's answer

```
public static final class OsUtils
{
   private static String OS = null;
   public static String getOsName()
   {
      if(OS == null) { OS = System.getProperty("os.name"); }
      return OS;
   }
   public static boolean isWindows()
   {
      return getOsName().startsWith("Windows");
   }

   public static boolean isUnix() // and so on
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get the os type using

```
System.getProperty("os.name")
```