# Java gui to call batch and shell by taking inputs from user

Tags: java, shell, batch-file, jython

Hi I am new to Java. I have written a Jython script to update some configurations in Websphere. It is having a text file (property.ini) where I am giving inputs like : where is my profile, where is my war file and some data to do configuration. My Jython will read these properties and do the configuration.

I am calling this Jython through batch or shell depending on OS. Initially my batch/shell will set 1 property in Websphere which is a prerequisite, and then restart server, and then call my Jython to do the required configuration.

Now I need a GUI written in Java where whatever data the user was giving in property file should be given through the GUIand it in turn should call a batch file if it is windows, or it should call shell if it's Linux/Unix.

Comment: Property file contains below data:Install EAr=true/false
Install NSB =true/false
Profile path=d:/ibm/websphere/appserver/profile/appsrv01
War path=d:/ibm/war
It even have 4 qeue connection factory name with its jndi name
28 qeue names with its jndi name
31 name space binding name
Qeue manager name 
Qeuemanager port
Databse name
Db port 
Dbusr/pwd)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. We would like to help, but as it is I do not think anyone can really tell what you need help with. Please read through [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and edit your question. As best I can tell, you want to [determine the host OS of a Java process](http://stackoverflow.com/q/228477/2970947). Is that where you're stuck?

Comment: I need to write java coded GUI which accepts inputs from user which writes back to .ini file and I have a shell script and batch script. My GUI should call shell/ batch script based on OS selected from user in GUI.

Comment: Why make the user select the OS? Your application can determine that at run-time.

Comment: yes that is also a good thing. So I need codes to implement it.