# How to read file on Windows and Linux from Java

Tags: java, linux, file-io, filereader

I have a xml file located in `D:\XML\RequestXML` and I am reading xml file in this folder from a `FileReader`. In my program I hard coded the file path `/XML/RequestXML/`. This works fine with the `windows` environment. In windows `JBoss` is in `D:\jbossdistrib\jboss`.

I created the folder structure in `linux` `/usr/XML/RequestXML/`. And add the xml in to RequestXML folder.  `JBoss` is in `/usr/jbossdistrib/jboss/` path.

But my application can not find the file specified in /XML/RequestXML/  in linux environment.

If I change the file path as `/usr/XML/RequestXML/` it works in linux.

How can I use the consistent file path in linux and windows both?

```
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

  private String filePath = "/XML/RequestXML/";

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

       String file = request.getParameter("fileName");

       xml =  readFile(filePath + file);

    }

  private String readFile(String file) {
    StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer();
    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        char[] buf = new char[1024];
        int numRead=0;

        while((numRead=reader.read(buf)) != -1){
            String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
            fileData.append(readData);
            buf = new char[1024];
        }
        reader.close();

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        logger.fatal("File not found in specifid path "+ file);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        logger.fatal("Error while reading the xml file");
    }
    return fileData.toString();
 }
}
```

---

Update

My question is how to set the file path without `/usr/` which works fine in Windows. 
If this is not possible, then do I need to use the path as `/usr/XML/RequestXML/` in windows environment as well? so I have to create a folder structure like `D:\usr\XML\RequestXML` in windows.

Comment: If the file is in `/usr/XML/RequestXML` and you're trying to read it from `/XML/RequestXML`, then it will obviously not find the file, since the two locations are not the same... Why are you hard-coding the path?

Comment: If the paths are different you cannot hard code it for both systems.

Comment: I don't want two paths. I'm saying if I use /XML/RequetXML/ path. this does not work in linux. Linux wants /usr/XML/RequestXML/  path to work. I just want only one path which is working in both linux and windows. How can I do that?

Comment: post the relevant code you tried will help us to give solution of the exact scenario

Comment: You either need the path to be identical for both the systems or you need to tell your code that he's running one or the other. Also in `/XML/RequestXML/`, `/` is the root directory, you might have another problem here.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the current working directory  (test it with:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

you can hardcode a relative directory like ../../XML/RequestXML

For the record: although this may help, I still believe you should try to solve this with a configuration parameter or by loading it as a resource available in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

`I don't want two paths`

ok then put your the file in the resources folder of your application and try reading it this way

```
private String filePath  = className.getClass()
                                    .getResource("yourFileName").getPath();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
```

Comment: Even I use it in resource file, still I have to change it when upload to linux. Because linux path starts from /usr/ But in windows there nothing like that. It use the relative path from D drive.

Answer (score 1):

First a bit of bad news: FileReader is a utility class that as default uses the platform encoding: **non-portable**. As the encoding is defined in the XML source itself, you might keep to InputStream if possible.

You could keep the XML as read-only resource *inside* the war/ear.

Or as read-only resource in the jboss directories, *outside* the application. Using as java resource via the system ClassLoader of jboss.

Or as file, where the path is configured as above. Maybe in an existing properties/xml configuration file.
You could also use the jboss admin console to configure a path.

Maybe of interest:

```
System.getProperty("file.encoding"); // The default encoding
System.getProperty("user.name"); // Under which user are we running
System.getProperty("user.home"); // The user's home
System.getProperty("user.dir"); // The applications working dir
```

JBoss also defines a couple of things; but that would be non-portable.

Comment: No there can be many xml files in this folder which user selects and submit. So I can not put them inside the war or ear. Also user would change the xml values time to time.

Comment: As Linux can have soft links (`link -s`), you have some freedom to define some common path, in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't easy to solve because of the fundamental differences in the file systems. (**Edit: Ignore me, I'm clearly on Cough Medicine. As Djon pointed out below**).

*Windows\Uses\Folder\Structures\Like\This.txt*

*Linux/Uses/Folder/Structures/Like/This.txt*

*So, the only way to handle this accordingly is to detect the operating system it runs on first, and then build your file paths accordingly.*

See this question for more details:

[How do I programmatically determine operating system in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java)

Comment: Well I'll be damned. Every time I've done something similar it's always had an issue. Just tried it in Explorer, Command Prompt, and a small script, and it worked. Thanks Djon!

Comment: Yes, This is not about '/' This is about /usr/ folder matter. How to read the file relatively. In windows, the path is taking from D drive onwards. But in linux it requre /usr/ additionally. My issue is how to resolve this.

Comment: Uh well, I was talking about Java, but I also tested it and in fact you're right, so I've learn something today...

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoding file paths is not a recommended practice. You may find a way to build the file path programmatically and use File.separator, which returns the correct one depending on the system ("\" for Windows, and "/" for UNIX/Linux/Macintosh).

Comment: Not necessarily, Java will take care of that and using `/` on windows works perfectly.