# Read file from Linux and windows using Java

Tags: java

I had been through this [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307720/read-file-from-windows-and-linux-from-java) but did not get proper answer.

I have `conf.txt` in Windows folder `c:\winapp\Game\core\conf.txt`

I have `conf.txt` in Linux folder `/usr/Game/core/conf.txt`

So, I know the relative path that starts from `Game` folder

Without using OS specific code like `System.getProperty("")`, Do we have an approach to write a portable Java program?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

I haven't used Windows regularly in a number of years, so I don't know if "c:\winapp" is a 'standard' directory, but there is nothing in Java libraries that would automagically associate c:\winapp on Windows with /usr on Linux.

So, you'd either have to detect the OS at runtime, and use the appropriate path (hard-coded into your application) or go with System.getProperty(), and have the user set the system property.

A slightly better approach might be to put the configuration file in the user's home directory.
Then, you could do System.getProperty("user.home"), and the user wouldn't have to set anything.

Comment: `winapp` is the folder created by the product installer, sorry to confuse you

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

I expect you know, how your application is packed. E.g.

```
/core/conf.txt
/lib/*.jar
/bin/*.(sh|cmd|exe)
```

In this case you can use

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String home = System.getenv("GAME_HOME"); // For dev environment.
    File appHome;

    if (home == null) {
        File libs = new File(Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
        appHome = new File(libs, "..");
    }
    else {
        appHome = new File(home);
    }

    appHome = appHome.getCanonicalFile();
    System.out.println("App home directory: " + appHome);
}
```

Of course Test class should be placed in one of the lib/*.jar files.