# Java's "os.name" for Windows 10?

Tags: java, operating-system, jvm, windows-10, getproperty

In Java, we can see the property value of `os.name` to know the name of the underlying operating system: `System.getProperty("os.name")`.

For each edition of Windows, it used to return always the exact name of the OS: `Windows XP` for XP, `Windows Vista` for Vista, `Windows 7` for Seven, `Windows 8.1` for 8.1, and so on...

The problem is: I just updated my Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 using the released Microsoft updater, and it seems like this property still remains `Windows 8.1`:

```
public class OSTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));
  }
}
```

How can I create a workaround for this? And, does anyone know if this problem persists if installing a fresh Windows 10 copy - that is, this bug is caused by the Microsoft auto-updater -?

Comment: Which Java version are you running this on (not that I have any idea how to fix this, other than perhaps to await a Java or Windows upgrade/fix)?

Comment: I'm running JDK 1.8.0_40

Comment: Have you rebooted? What is the result of [`ver`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ver_%28command%29) on the command line?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: in order to upgrade the OS, he has absolutely has to reboot.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels In order to complete a Windows Upgrade? Of course. And you're sure he has done so? Some of us aren't enchanters Tim.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is a known bug:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8057122

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: yeah, [we do know that he has to reboot](http://www.howtogeek.com/197559/how-to-install-windows-10-on-your-pc/). It's required for the PC to run after the upgrade.

Comment: Verified from cold start, Java 1.8, Windows 10.  Windows ver command prints `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]` - So I guess "a" work around is to invoke the `ver` command from within Java

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/954296/javas-system-properties-returning-windows-8-1-after-upgrade-to-windows-10

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is a known problem [JDK-8066504](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8066504) that has been fixed in upcoming Java 8 update 60.

The reason is [GetVersionEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx) function has changed its behavior since Windows 8.1.

There are multiple possible workarounds, see [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724429(v=vs.85).aspx).

The trivial one is to exec `cmd.exe /c ver`.

The other is to look at the version information of one of the system files, e.g. `kernel32.dll`.

Answer (score 17):

This is definitely a known bug. It occurs because the `os.name` property gets its value from the `GetVersionEx` in the source code of the Windows API. `GetVersionEx` however,

> may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1

As per Microsoft's official website. Instead, we will need to use the `IsWindows10OrGreater` found in the Version Helper API functions in the `versionhelpers.h` file. As you probably guessed though, this file is not a Java file, it is written in C. As a result we need to include it in a somewhat roundabout way. It does take quite a bit of work (you need to program in JNI :/) but [this tutorial](http://jonisalonen.com/2012/calling-c-from-java-is-easy/) will help you do it. Another solution is shown in [this bug log](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8059803), and does require less effort.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, used the following workaround:
The cmd command "systeminfo" returns "OS Name:" which is the right name for the OS, wrote the following function for this:

```
private boolean os2k10Check()
{
try{

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("systeminfo");        /*Execute cmd command "systeminfo"*/
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) 
    {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) { break; }
        if(line.contains("OS Name:"))               /*If output contains OS Name and 2010*/
        {
        if(line.contains("2010"))
                return true;
        else
                return false;       
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
    {System.out.println("Platform Type: os2010check: exception"+e);}

return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hm... I don't know if it is a fix of Windows 10(`10.0.17134.590`) or of Java 8(`1.8.0_171-b11` for me), but it is correct now: `os.name` gives me `Windows 10`.

Besides, if you don't trust it, you can check `os.version`. I have `10.0`.

(By the way, I see `os.arch:amd64`. This is of JVM, not of OS. )

Answer (score -23):

You could also use the `.contains()` method and just check for the "windows"
string maybe along the lines of

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows") && System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains(windows version here [xp, 7, 8, etc]))){}
```

If you need the windows version you could check for all versions and then assume 8.1 or 10 to move around the bug.

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows") && System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("xp")){
//code for windows xp }

else if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows") && System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("vista")){
//code for windows vista

else if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows") && System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("7")){
//code for windows 7}

else if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows") && System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("8")){
//code for windows 8}
else if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows") && System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("8.1")){
//code for both windows 8.1 and 10

}
```

Now to explain what is going on here:

1. the if statement is just a conditional to determine the version of windows
2. The `System.getProperty("os.name")` returns the name of the os as a string
3. The `.toLowerCase()` method makes that returned String lower case
4. The `.contains(String)` method checks if the given input string is contained in the String it is being called on
5. The last statement allows for different code for each os except 8.1 & 10 which would need to be handled as one block :(

Comment: "The last statement allows for different code for each os except 8.1 & 10". That's EXACTLY what OP DOESN'T want. So, this answer literally does everything BUT answer the question.