# Java's system properties returning "Windows 8.1" after upgrade to "Windows 10"

Tags: windows-8.1, java, windows-10, properties

My upgrade to Windows 10 went very well and only needing a few programs reinstalled. Java was one of those because Eclipse did not start anymore: eclipse 64 bit didn't run but 32 bit did and I am on a 64 bit machine where it used to work. This was easily fixed by uninstalling and reinstalling Java and the JDK. However, one issue still remains.

`System.getProperty(" ... ")` returns next wrong values:

- `"os.name" = "Windows 8.1"` should say `"Windows 10"`
- `"os.version" = "6.3"` is this wrong also?

Is this a problem with Java or is this because Windows 10 was done through a system-update and my system is technically still "Windows 8.1"?

Comment: I can't speak as to why you're getting those results, but it looks like the os.version is wrong too, the early versions of windows 10 had version 6.4, but I believe the finished, publicly released, version is 10.0.10240.

Comment: You are correct, I just did "ver" in command prompt and it says Version 10.0.10240. That does mean os.version is wrong too.

Comment: Why was this migrated from superuser to stackoverflow? This hardly is a programming question.

Comment: @RoyT. of course it is a programming related question, he is getting the windows properties for programming purpose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java's "os.name" for Windows 10?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909107/javas-os-name-for-windows-10)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a problem with current Java.

MS changed some API behavior in Windows 10 and Java doesn't recognise it correctly. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8059803 for details.

This will be fixed in upcoming **jdk8u60**. Latest dev version reports next on Windows 10:

```
os.name = Windows 10
os.version = 10.0
```