# Jenkins Showing Windows 10 Node As Windows 8.1

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I recently upgraded a Windows 7 node to Windows 10, but Jenkins is showing Windows 8.1 in the "Architecture" column. Is there some sort of reference that isn't linking up with the new configuration?

Comment: If your Windows node is connected via Java and has an old Java build, it could be https://stackoverflow.com/q/31909107/855954