# How to detect which OS a program is running on and use the correct path format

Tags: java, linux, windows, spring-mvc, log4j

Good day

I am new to log4j, I want to deploy a web app on an windows and Linux server so if the app is on windows it will use a path like c:/logs/appLogFile.log and if its running on Linux it will be something like /opt/app/logs/appLogFile.log I know you can set the path of the log file in the log4j.properties file but is there a way to for me to test on which OS its running and use the specified path for that OS. I am also using spring as a framework

Thank you in advance

Comment: The path separator on windows is a backslash (\\). Depending on the Windows APIs that log4j calls it may or may not convert / to \. See [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx) for additional details.

Comment: Thank you that was pretty useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java).

Also, if you are using Maven, you may want to look into [build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to assist in managing different environments.

Comment: Thank you very much this has helped