# Provide different method name in interface

Tags: java, shared-libraries, jna

I'm complete Java ignorant, yet I've to resolve this problem. I'm using JNA and have in one file:

```
public interface JRockey4ND extends Library {

    public short rockey(short func, short[] handle, int[] lp1, int[] lp2, short[] p1, short[] p2, short[] p3, short[] p4, byte[] buffer);
    public short RY_FIND=1;
    public short RY_FIND_NEXT=2;
}
```

and in another file:

```
JRockey4ND rockey = (JRockey4ND) Native.loadLibrary(libFileName, JRockey4ND.class);
.
.
retval=rockey.rockey(rockey.RY_FIND,handle[0],lp1,lp2,p1,p2,p3,p4,buffer);
```

and it works like a charm. But depending on platform, I have to use `Rockey` method instead of `rockey` due to exported symbols naming mismatch between Linux .so and Windows .dll. I've tried to replace symbol name in so file by using: `perl -pi -e 's/rockey/Rockey/g' lib.so` but it doesn't work ( symbol 'Rockey' can't be found after that, despite of replacement ).

So my question is, how this can be resolved programmatically in easiest possible way ( not the prettiest one ). Many thanks!

Comment: In this case you probably don't want to be trying to control the capitalization of symbols exported from libraries. Why not perform a check for which OS you're running and make the appropriate call? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java

Comment: You could try and use reflection, e.g. depending on the OS you look for the method "rockey" or "Rockey" in `JRockey4ND.class`.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, sounds very good. But how should I modify my interface so it will be able to provide both methods? I can't just check OS directly in body of interface.

Comment: Hmm, I'd probably not change the interface but check the implementation class returned by the `loadLibrary` call, i.e. use `rockey.getClass()` to get it. Then use `getMethod("rockey", <parameter types>)` to get the lower case method. If it doesn't exist, i.e. you get a `MethodNotFoundException`, try with method name `"Rockey"` then. However, the problem is that I didn't use JNA for a while so I don't know whether you can load the library at all if the method names don't fit. If that's the case then you'd probably be better off solving the case problem.

Comment: Is `Rockey` a 3rd party library? If so, is there a way to recompile it and change the names during symbol generation/export? If not, you might try and write an adapter that provides the method names in the correct case and delegates the calls to the actual library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [JNA JavaDoc](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/overview-summary.html#overview_description), you can provide a [`FunctionMapper`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/FunctionMapper.html) as an option when initializing your library which maps the method name to the library name.

```
FunctionMapper mapper = new FunctionMapper() {
    public String getFunctionName(NativeLibrary library, Method method) {
    if (Platform.isWindows()) {
        if (method.getName().equals("rocket")) {
            return "Rocket";
        }
    }
    return method.getName();
```

}
    };
    Map options = new HashMap();
    options.put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, mapper);
    Native.loadLibrary("rocket", Rocket.class, options);