# Equivalent of Maven profiles in SBT

Tags: maven, sbt, lwjgl

I've got a `pom.xml` that has some profiles defined that check the operating system it's being run on and changes a variable based on the operating system. Is there an equivalent to this sort of behaviour in SBT?

[The pom.xml I'm looking at (it's the LWJGL one)](http://pastebin.com/953yJq6B)

Answer (score 1):

General you should change your mind. In SBT you use plain scala with all libraries.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>lwjgl-natives-linux></id>
        <activation>
            <os><family>unix</family></os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <lwjgl.natives>natives-linux</lwjgl.natives>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>lwjgl-natives-macos></id>
        <activation>
            <os><family>mac</family></os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <lwjgl.natives>natives-macos</lwjgl.natives>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>lwjgl-natives-windows></id>
        <activation>
            <os><family>windows</family></os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <lwjgl.natives>natives-windows</lwjgl.natives>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

According to your example, define the variable. (See [How do I programmatically determine operating system in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18417382/651140)):

```scala
val lwjglNatives = sys.props("os.name").toLowerCase match {
    case os if os.contains("uni") =>
            "natives-linux"
    case os if os.contains("mac") | os.contains("darwin") =>
       "natives-macos"
    case os if os.contains("win") =>
       "natives-windows"    
}
```

Then you can use `lwjglNatives` depending on OS.