# Firefox is not launching URL through Selenium WebDriver

Tags: eclipse, selenium, webdriver, eclipse-photon

I am using Eclipse Photon, Firefox version 62.0 Quantum, Selenium 3.14.0, geckodriver version 0.21.0.

When I run the code, Firefox opens but doesn't launch the URL. 
Everything is up-to-date, geckodriver is set as marionette.
Please help.

My code is:

```
package firstSelenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty(
                "webdriver.firefox.marionette", 
                "C:\\Users\\nargi\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe"
        );

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: As answered by amsankalp89 please update Property to gecko driver and code will work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start FireFoxDriver using Selenium 3.4.0 using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757984/how-to-start-firefoxdriver-using-selenium-3-4-0-using-maven)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check the compatibility of your geckoDriver and your Mozilla Firefox driver. 
In my system I am using geckoDriver version as 0.21.0 and my MozillaFF browser is FireFox Quantam 64 bit version 61.0.1. In my system this code works fine.

```
class Test{
public static void main(String args[]){
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", path);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
}
```

}

Please check the compatibility and let me know if it works. 
Also verify that path to geckoDriver is correct and there is no other .exe file named as geckodriver.exe

Comment: Hi, my geckodriver version is 0.21.0 and firefox quantum  version 63.o beta version. it looks like i wrote the path wrong to the geckodriver. It worked!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, in that case, my answer is also correct:) Anyway @Mukul Maheshwari there is no difference in my and your answer. +1

Comment: Yes @iamsankalp89 as Narcissa said, the geckodriver path was incorrect in code, there was no other code issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use correct `setProperty`, as you are using gecko driver, so you need to use `"webdriver.gecko.driver"`

Correct code is

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\nargi\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
}
}
```

Comment: I think it should work for you Please check it once. it helps you please accept or any help needed let me know

Comment: I have tried this way, but i keep getting an error message Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\nargi\Downloads\geckodriver.exe

Comment: I will check as my side there is no issue, try with updated selenium jars

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue was solved when "marionette" was changed to "gecko.driver"