# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LINUX

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
package org.example;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Asus\\Downloads\\jar_files (1)\\selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.guru99.com");
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

With this code I get the following error:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program
>   Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
>   2019.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=59685:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath
>   "C:\Users\Asus\Maven
>   wokspace\target\classes;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi\3.12\poi-3.12.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml\3.12\poi-ooxml-3.12.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml-schemas\3.12\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans\2.6.0\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\stax\stax-api\1.0.1\stax-api-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\webdriver\webdriver-common\0.9.7376\webdriver-common-0.9.7376.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\3.141.59\selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\3.141.59\selenium-api-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\3.141.59\selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.8.15\byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\25.0-jre\guava-25.0-jre.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-compat-qual\2.0.0\checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.1.3\error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.1\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\animal-sniffer-annotations\1.14\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\com\squareup\okhttp3\okhttp\3.11.0\okhttp-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\com\squareup\okio\okio\1.14.0\okio-1.14.0.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\7.1.0\testng-7.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\com\beust\jcommander\1.72\jcommander-1.72.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\4.1.0\guice-4.1.0-no_aop.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\Asus.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.21\snakeyaml-1.21.jar"
>   org.example.Sample
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LINUX
>
> at org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.(PortProber.java:43)
>
> at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:351)
>
> at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
>
> at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>
> at org.example.Sample.main(Sample.java:8)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Anybody tell me the exact solution?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LINUX
```

...implies that the `Platform.LINUX` field in the source is absent.

---

It is also pretty much evident from the error trace logs that you are using [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) and this error can happen in the following cases:

- Old and incompatible binaries.
- CLASSPATH conflict i.e. similar jar file already present with in the project.

---

### Solution

You have to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- You need to replace the caps `W` with small **`w`** as follows:

  ```
  "webdriver.chrome.driver"
  ```
- As you are using [Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757984/how-to-start-firefoxdriver-using-selenium-3-4-0-using-maven/43759644#43759644):

  - If you have added the `selenium-chrome-driver` dependency you don't need to use the `System.setProperty()` line.
  - You need to execute the following commands to flush out the previous dependencies, install the new dependencies & execute your test:

  > mvn clean
  >   mvn install
  >   mvn test

  - In a worst case scenario you may have delete the **`.m2`** i.e. **MAVEN_HOME** sub-directory and re-install the dependencies to execute your test.

Further, ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.