# Java code to find operating system

Tags: java

I am very new at coding in Java and I want to write a code to find out my operating system through a dialogue box (Windows). I wrote this code but I am not sure how to completely implement it.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong in simple terms as I am a beginner.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class JavaTut {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,System.getProperty("os.name").list(System.out));
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
 }
}
```

Comment: don't use a screenshot copy the code into the post and format it.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `System.getProperty("os.name").list(System.out)`, use `System.getProperty("os.name")`.

Example `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, System.getProperty("os.name"));
}
```

Comment: @Biogrid many thanks is useless with out accepting it as answer.