# Conditional builddir in gradle per OS

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I develop locally in a Windows PC and I have my build machine in OSX and or Linux. Since some of the files have over 255 characters I changed my build path like this:

```
buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
```

Now this won't work in any UNIX system. How can I make it dynamic so it works in Windows, OSX and Linux? I am trying to find a variable but I dont have that much experience in gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Os`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/api/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/condition/Os.html) class from ant

Try something like this :

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

def prefix = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? 'C:/' : '/'
buildDir = prefix + "tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
```

Comment: Awesome. I only had to change the single quotes to double quotes so the variables get replaced but this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is built on top of Groovy, which is a JVM language just like Java. Therefore, you can use the same method(s) you can use [in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java).