# SBT: dynamically detect building platform

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying dynamically change reference to the jars dependency I am using in my project, depending on the platform (Windows or Linux)

So, its a very trivial scenario,

How can I implement this simple check in the build.sbt ?

Comment: Does something like this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java

Comment: Looks like this is a code I need, just have to execute it in the build time, let me try, thank you !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Potential approach is to pattern match on `System.getProperty("os.name")` within a [custom defined setting](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Custom-Settings.html) like so

```
val configureDependencyByPlatform = settingKey[ModuleID]("Dynamically change reference to the jars dependency depending on the platform")
configureDependencyByPlatform := {
  System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase match {
    case mac if mac.contains("mac")  => "org.example" %% "somelib-mac" % "1.0.0"
    case win if win.contains("win") => "org.example" %% "somelib-win" % "1.0.0"
    case linux if linux.contains("linux") => "org.example" %% "somelib-linux" % "1.0.0"
    case osName => throw new RuntimeException(s"Unknown operating system $osName")
  }
}
```

and then add the evaluated setting to `libraryDependencies` as follows

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  configureDependencyByPlatform.value,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5",
  ...
)
```

Comment: 1. Is there something similar I can use in the scope of git submodules?? as I need to have  two different versions of how projects would resolved locally (Windows)  and on the build sever (Linux), I have sbt multiproject etc. 2. This build.sbt approach is looking good, I hope I will use in the project, but what I've used so far, is actually build in -> unmanagedJars (https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html), which is nicely resolving locations I need.