# How to find whether a process is running on Windows/Linux

Tags: java, detection, obs

I want my program to be able to detect whether OBS-Studio is currently running, and if it is, perform certain functionality in my program. The problem is I can't seem to find a solution that will work on both platforms. I've found things that use `taskList`, `wmic.exe` and others on windows, and I've found things using `top`, `ps aux` and others on linux, however these are very platform specific, and not easily ported. Is there a universal use case, and if so, what might it be?

I'm aware of ProcessHandle in Java9+, however my program runs Java8, with no current hope of upgrading, so that's not possible.

Comment: As far as I know, in java 8 there is no API for listing all the OS processes. I suggest using the java System property to discover the the host OS and then launch the command for that OS which lists the processes.

Comment: [How do I programmatically determine operating system in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228477/5221149)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a method that would return a `Map<Integer, String>` for all processes by running os-specific commands:

```
public Map<Integer, String> getProcesses() {
    final Map<Integer, String> processes = Maps.newHashMap();
    final boolean windows = System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows");
    try {
        final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(windows ? "tasklist /fo csv /nh" : "ps -e");
        try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
            reader.lines().skip(1).forEach(x -> { // the first line is usually just a line to explain the format
                if (windows) {
                    // "name","id","type","priority","memory?"
                    final String[] split = x.replace("\"", "").split(",");
                    processes.put(Integer.valueOf(split[1]), split[0]);
                }
                else {
                    // id tty time command
                    final String[] split = Arrays.stream(x.trim().split(" ")).map(String::trim)
                            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).toArray(String[]::new); // yikes
                    processes.put(Integer.valueOf(split[0]), split[split.length - 1]);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return processes;
}
```

This hasn't been tested on Windows, but it should work. It also hasn't been tested on literally anything else other than Linux, but I hope this serves as a helpful method for others to work off of.

Answer (score 0):

I Cannot think of a solution that will work on both platforms,
maybe use something like below to determine the operating system in Java then from there, use a conditional statement to execute the portion of the code appropriate for your host machine.

```
os = System.getProperty("os.name");
```

I hope this helps