# How to get OS details using java

Tags: java

I know we can use `System.getProperty("os.name");` to get the os name. But due to some reason someone has set an environment variable called `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dos.name=Windows 7"` which is causing not to get the original OS name instead its always getting the OS name as Window 7.

Do we have any way where we can get the original OS details?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I programmatically determine operating system in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java)

Comment: Unfortunately no. My question here is System.getProperty is not behaving correctly due the environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.

Comment: If this actually is Windows and 'someone' is only faking the version not the platform, `os.version` is the MS internal version which _mostly_ (but not completely) maps to the `os.name` values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache Commons Lang, class name is `SystemUtils`. You can use the below code.

```
String osName = SystemUtils.OS_NAME;
System.out.println("OS NAME: " + osName);
```

You have to add the Apache Commons Lang in the classpath.

If nothing works then you have to execute the commands specific to OS one by one until you get the correct result. But this is not the correct approach, it is just a work around.

For Windows, execute `ver`

For Linux, execute `cat /etc/*-release` or `lsb_release -a`

Comment: I just saw the implementation of SystemUtils. Here also we are using System.getProperty.

`private static String getSystemProperty(final String property) {
        try {
            return System.getProperty(property);
        } catch (final SecurityException ex) {
            // we are not allowed to look at this property
            System.err.println("Caught a SecurityException reading the system property '" + property
                    + "'; the SystemUtils property value will default to null.");
            return null;
        }
    }`

Comment: Thanks but my question here is System.getProperty is not behaving correctly due the environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.

Comment: If possible, can you remove `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dos.name=Windows 7"` from environment variable and check system property in java just to pin point the issue ?

Comment: yes.. if i remove then this works..but unfortunately we can't remove this variable as some other software requires this entry.

Comment: @NagarajuChitimilla Then remove that property from the global environment, and only set it for the specific program that does require it.